# codeigniter error with call to undefined function codeigniter\locale_set_default() search

Tags: php, codeigniter-4, intl

This is the error I see in CodeIgnitor 4 on a new server installation.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\locale_set_default()
```

When I look at potential problems I see that I have the intl extension installed  but when I do this command:

```
    php -i | grep -i intl
```

returns

```
    intl.default_locale => no value => no value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution I've found is to edit the PHP configuration files and add:

```
   intl.default_locale="en-US"
```

I added it to /etc/php.d/20-intl.ini but your local configuration may vary.

Then I tested the apache configuration and restarted:

```
    apachectl configtest
    apachectl restart
```

The error didn't go away so I continued my search and found php-fpm was running:

```
    ps auxwww | grep -i PHP
```

which returned

```
apache   10499  0.0  0.4 292148 16672 ?        S    17:07   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache   10502  0.0  0.4 292148 16696 ?        S    17:07   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache   10503  0.0  0.3 290076 13756 ?        S    17:07   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache   10504  0.0  0.3 290076 13768 ?        S    17:07   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache   10506  0.0  0.2 288028 11624 ?        S    17:07   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
apache   20201  0.0  0.3 290076 13744 ?        S    17:16   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

so I restarted that service with this command:

```
    service php-fpm restart
```

and now everything seems to be running perfectly. There were still a few permissions issues to address with a new install of CodeIgnitor but those are for another post.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to adding an actual locale like this in php.ini file:

```
intl.default_locale="en-US"
```

ensure that this extension is enabled... in other words remove the `;` in this line...

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

and after a restart this fixed for me.