# Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\locale_set_default() - Xampp

Tags: codeigniter, xampp, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to set up Codeigniter4 with Xampp but when calling the public address `http://localhost/projectfolder/public/index.php` as stated in the `README.md` file of the CodeIgniter4 framework, the next error appears:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\locale_set_default() in
C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter4\system\CodeIgniter.php:184
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter4\system\bootstrap.php(181): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter-&gt;initialize()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter4\public\index.php(36): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#2 {main}
thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter4\system\CodeIgniter.php</b> on line <b>184</b><br />
```

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68154368/codeigniter-error-with-call-to-undefined-function-codeigniter-locale-set-default) but it didn't work for me.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Please follow this solution here. I answer this question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58409729/11716584)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my temporary solution in [here](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/3171#issuecomment-734558338), without updating de PHP Version in Xampp.

Go to `C:\xampp\htdocs\projectfolder\system\CodeIgniter.php - line 184` and change the next line.

Before:

```
locale_set_default($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
```

After:

```
if( function_exists('locale_set_default' ) ) :
    locale_set_default($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
    endif;
```

Once I updated Xampp to the 7.4 version ([download here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/)), I just needed to enable the `extension=intl` in the `xampp\php\php.ini` file. As it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55865030/15782338), you just have to uncomment the line from `;extension=intl` to `extension=intl`.

Then you can leave the `C:\xampp\htdocs\projectfolder\system\CodeIgniter.php - line 184` as it was in the beginning.

```
locale_set_default($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
```

Comment: Disabling the use of one function in the framework doesn't solve the fundamental issue.

Comment: You are right [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7376590/steven7mwesigwa). I didn't notice one of my desktops were still working in an old version of Xampp and also with an old version of PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The root of the issue is that you have a missing PHP extension.
In particular:

- [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php)

Keep in mind that this is **clearly** stated in the frameworks' repository README.md file.

[Server Requirements](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4#server-requirements)

> PHP version 7.4 or higher is required, with the following extensions
> installed:
>
> - [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php)
> - [libcurl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.requirements.php) if you plan to use the HTTP\CURLRequest library
> - [mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php)
>
> Additionally, make sure that the following extensions are enabled in
> your PHP:
>
> - json (enabled by default - don't turn it off)
> - xml (enabled by default - don't turn it off)
> - [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php)

In addition, it's also pointed out here:

[Bug: Missing function locale_set_default(...) #3171](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/3171#issuecomment-650177614)

> Please install `intl` extension - this is a required component.

Answer (score 0):

Install it via linux

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

or for a PHP Version

```
sudo apt install php7.4-intl
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are on xampp (windows) update the php.ini

php.ini path = C:\xampp\php\php.ini

;extension=intl

to

extension=intl