# Codeigniter 4 Class "Locale" not found

Tags: codeigniter-4

Please if you have a solution to this codeigniter4 error help out [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO94n.png)

Codeigniter4 homepage failing to display but shows out that error

Comment: Please share the full error stack trace. As it currently stands, it's unclear if the error spawns from userland source code or from CodeIgniter 4 system core files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\locale\_set\_default() - Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434878/call-to-undefined-function-codeigniter-locale-set-default-xampp)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 12):

This error occurs if the `intl` extension is not installed, as specified in the system requirements.

Follow these steps to fix the class `Locale` not found error:

1. Locate this file in XAMP OR WAMP, the `php.ini` file
2. Find this `;extension=intl` line and remove the semi-colon
3. Restart the server