# Class "Locale" not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, intl

`Class "Locale" not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\rabantonV3\system\I18n\TimeTrait.php:74`

i've enable extension=intl with remove ; in php.ini and restart apache service but still got error class locale not found
my CI version is CI 4.4.3
my php version is 8.2

Comment: @JaromandaX just a typo, it should be php

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509500/codeigniter-4-class-locale-not-found) help?

Comment: `$this->locale = $locale ?: Locale::getDefault();`

Comment: huh? does this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509500/codeigniter-4-class-locale-not-found help?

Comment: @JaromandaX doesn't help, still getting the same error

Comment: so you have done those three steps, all three, not just the ones you wan to do?

Comment: what about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434878/call-to-undefined-function-codeigniter-locale-set-default-xampp) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852169/whoops-we-seem-to-have-hit-a-snag-please-try-again-later/58409729#58409729)

Comment: You need to enable `intl` extenstion. Check with `phpinfo()`, you will have to see a section `intl`. If you don't, then the intl extension is either not installed or enabled.

Comment: change `Locale::getDefault();` to `\Locale::getDefault();` for make sure you use class Locale from global namespace or add `use Locale;` on the top file.